# Eclipse scala "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: scala

I have just started learning scala, i am using the eclipse ide for it, in the run configuration i have set *scala application* with the project name and as main class *main* when i compile i have

> Error: Could not find or load main class main

when i check the console i see it's reading from Java/jre directory, is it normal or should i change that ?
This is the code

```
package one

class Main {
object Bottles {
    def main(args: Array[String]){
        var n : Int=2;
        while(n<=6){
            println(s"Hello ${n} bottles");
            n+=1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, also had the same error Error: "Could not find or load main class main" in my Scala IDE and the reason of that was that when I created Main, I immediately moved it to a package.

So I had to:

- Move my main class back to default package.
- Clean, compile, run.

Comment: package should not have been a problem.  It is recommended to always use a package name.  Probably you only needed to do a clean after fixing the code.

Comment: No I did clean and it didn't help, why do you say clean is a silver bullet?

Comment: @puhlen: this might be due to the "Java Build Path" being set to `src` , not `src/main/scala`. Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

The `main` method needs to be on a toplevel object. Your `Bottles` object is wrapped in a `Main` class. Remove that `Main` class and your code should run.

```
object Bottles {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    var n : Int=2;
    while(n<=6){
      println(s"Hello ${n} bottles");
      n+=1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I removed the Main class and i still have the same error

Comment: Maybe the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35477972/scala-how-to-define-a-value-class ?