# scala: how to define a value class

Tags: scala

Quick question regrading how to define a value class in scala

Here is typical example:

```
class Wrapper(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal
```

I am getting next error:

```
/usr/home/User/scala2/scala_lerning/src3/val.scala:1: error: value class may not be a member of another class
class Wrapper(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal
      ^
one error found
```

OS: FreeBSD 10.2
Scala code runner version 2.11.7 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

Could anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: The error message seems pretty explicit, a value class cannot be an inner class.

Comment: Sorry, still open question for me. I am compiling this from command promt like: scala value.scala . Should I apply any class modifier in example above?

Comment: Error messages don't get much clearer than this...

Comment: Should I specify any options to compiler?

Comment: Seems to be related to how the `scala` command loads files. Compiling with `scalac` works fine, same with simply typing the line in the REPL or using `:load` within it.

Comment: Thanks, scalac is the right solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're doing

```
class Foo {
  class Wrapper(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal
}
```

which you can't. You have to do

```
class Foo {
}
class Wrapper(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal
```

Comment: I am getting the same error when I am putting your code in a single file and trying to compile: scala file.scala.

Comment: Here is also example from scala documentation. It also fails:                                     trait Printable extends Any {
  def print(): Unit = println(this)
}
class Wrapper(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal with Printable
val w = new Wrapper(3)
w.print() // actually requires instantiating a Wrapper instance

Comment: That's because you're invoking `scala file.scala` instead of `scalac file.scala`. Apparently `scala` wraps everything into a toplevel class to enable scripting.